# Why does `ranges::view::for_each` require the functor must return a model of the `InputRange` concept?

Tags: c++, standards, concept, c++20, range-v3

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::vector{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::for_each(coll.begin(), coll.end(), [](auto){}); // ok
    coll | view::for_each([](auto){}); // static_assert failure
}
```

The `static_assert` error message:

> To use view::for_each, the function F must return a model of the
>   InputRange concept.

`std::for_each` takes a functor which returns `void`, why does `ranges::view::for_each` require the functor must return a model of the `InputRange` concept?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You misunderstand what `view::for_each()` is, it's totally different from `std::for_each`.

The functor in `view::for_each()` should return another range, then the final effect is that all the ranges are flattened to a big range.

For example:

```
auto res = coll | view::for_each([](auto n){ return yield_from(view::ints(0, n)); });
```

The returned range for every element is `{0}`, `{0, 1}`, `{0, 1, 2}` respectively. The `res` will be the flattened one: `{0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2}`

The counterpart of `std::for_each` is `ranges::for_each`:

```
ranges::for_each(coll, [] (auto) {})
```

Comment: **"You misunderstand what view::for_each() is, it's totally different from std::for_each."** people should emphasize more on that.

Comment: If it gets included in C++23 Ranges, it'll be called `views::flat_map`: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2214r1.html#flat_map